# Is there any way to send a column value from outer query to inner sub query?

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, subquery

'Discussions' table schema

```
title      description    desid    replyto    upvote    downvote   views
browser    used           a1        none        1          1       12
-          bad topic      b2        a1          2          3       14
sql        database       a3        none        4          5       34
-          crome          b4        a3          3          4       12
```

The above table has two types of content types Main Topics and Comments. Unique content identifier 'desid' used to identify that its a main topic or a comment. 'desid' starts with 'a' for Main Topic and for comment 'desid' starts with 'b'. For comment 'replyto' is the 'desid' of main topic to which this comment is associated.

I like to find out the list of the top main topics that are arranged on the basis of (upvote+downvote+visits+number of comments to it) addition. The following query gives top topics list in order of  (upvote+downvote+visits)

`select *` with highest number of `upvote+downvote+views` by query

```
select * 
from [DB_user1212].[dbo].[discussions] 
where desid like 'a%'
order by (upvote+downvote+visited) desc
```

For (comments+upvote+downvote+views ) i tried

```
select *
from [DB_user1212].[dbo].[discussions]
where desid like 'a%'
order by (select count(*)
           from [DB_user1212].[dbo].[discussions]
           where replyto = desid )+upvote+downvote+visited) desc
```

but it didn't work . Because its not possible to send desid from outer query to innner subquery. Please tell me how to solve this. Please note that I want solution in query language only.

Comment: Shiva! do you think there is one who will answer your question which would be acceptable for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use table aliases:

```
select *
from [DB_user1212].[dbo].[discussions] d1 --alias
where desid like 'a%'
order by (select count(*)
           from [DB_user1212].[dbo].[discussions] d2
           where d2.replyto = d1.desid )+upvote+downvote+visited) desc
```

Now, in the subquery, you can refer to the outer tables by alias (here, `d1`). I also added `d2`, which is not necessary here, but it can be useful to be explicit in subqueries.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work:) let me know, please.

```
WITH x AS
    (
    select count(*) numberofcomments, replyto
               from [DB_user1212].[dbo].[discussions]
               GROUP BY replyto
    )

    select [DB_user1212].[dbo].[discussions].*
    from [DB_user1212].[dbo].[discussions]
    inner JOIN x 
    ON [DB_user1212].[dbo].[discussions].desid = x.replyto
    where desid like 'a%'
    ORDER BY (numberofcomments+upvote+downvote+visited)
```

Comment: Thanks Radu, it worked but in some cases it was not giving perfect results. But thanks for answering..+1 to you..